# Extend linear transormation from $L^p$ space to $L^q$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $1 < p < \infty$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Suppose that $$\|T(f)\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)} \le A\|f \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}$$ 
for all $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (in this case we say $T$ is bounded on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d))$ and
$$\int Tf(x)g(x)dx =\int f(x)Tg(x)dx$$ 
for all $f,g \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then show that $T$ extends uniquely to a bounded operator $ \widetilde{T} $ on $L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and  $\widetilde{T}$ satisﬁes 
$$ \|\widetilde{T}f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)} \le A\|f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)}.$$

I think after showing $T(g)\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $g ∈ L^p(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$, it would be easy to solve the problem. But I can not show it. I tried to think of $g$ as Dual of $L^p$ space and but the condition is given for both $f, g$ to be on intersection of $L^p$ and $L^q$ spaces. I would appreciate your answers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fix $g\in L^p \cap L^q$. For each $f\in L^p\cap L^q$, by Minkowski's inequality,
\begin{align*}
\left|\int f(x)Tg(x)\,dx\right| \leq \int|Tf(x)||g(x)|\,dx \leq A\|f\|_p\|g\|_q.
\end{align*}
Hence $f \mapsto \int fTg$ extends (by density arguments) to a continuous linear functional on $L^p$. That is, $Tg \in L^q$.